# pandas: merge/concat.join two dfs

Tags: pandas, join, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have 2 dfs which I want to merge/concat/join.

Here is df1:

```
 item    country  Month Year
 honda   JP       2     16
 sony    GB       6     16
 jazz    JP       6     16
 honda   US       6     16
 jazz    JP       1     16
```

Here is df2:

```
 item    country  pay 
 honda   JP       y   
 sony    GB       n   
 jazz    JP       y   
 honda   US       y   
 jazz    JP       n
```

Here is what I want the merge to look like:

```
 item    country  pay  Month Year
 honda   JP       y     2     16
 sony    GB       n     6     16
 jazz    JP       y     6     16
 honda   US       y     6     16
 jazz    JP       n     1     16
```

I used `df = df1.join(df2, how='outer')` but it created duplicates.

I would like to use the `item` and `country` columns to merge in the `pay` column, if that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) in both `DataFrames`:

```
print (pd.concat([df1.set_index(['item','country']),
                  df2.set_index(['item','country'])], axis=1).reset_index())
    item country  Month  Year pay
0  honda      JP      2    16   y
1   sony      GB      6    16   n
2   jazz      JP      6    16   y
3  honda      US      6    16   y
4   jazz      JP      1    16   n
```